# Limiting decimals according to variable in python

Tags: python, decimal

I'm trying to code a program that returns the [golden ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio) up to a limit of decimal places.
What I have so far is this:

```
def gr(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    for x in range(0, n):
        a, b = b, a+b
    else:
        return(a)

    decimals = int(input("What amount of decimals do you want to see of the golden ratio?"))
    ratio = gr(41)/gr(40)
    print(format(ratio, '2f'))
```

The problem is that I can't find a way to format `ratio` to the number in `decimals`.

Comment: Since you don't have a `break` in your `for` loop, I'm not really sure the `else` is needed here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the precision/decimals  variable to str.format:

```
decimals = int(input("What amount of decimals do you want to see of the golden ratio?"))
ratio = gr(41)/gr(40)
print("{:.{}f}".format(ratio,decimals))
```

Example:

```
In [3]: decimals = int(input("What amount of decimals do you want to see of the golden ratio?"))
What amount of decimals do you want to see of the golden ratio?5

In [4]: ratio = gr(41)/gr(40)

In [5]: print("{:.{}f}".format(ratio,decimals))
1.61803
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is an alternative to what you are trying to do:

```
print(round(ratio, 2))
```

The snippet above will round the value `ratio` to 2 decimal places.  So to do it for the integer in decimals, you could do:

```
print(round(ratio, decimals))
```

Comment: How is that any different from what I posted?

Comment: try using both and then you tell me

Comment: He did not request a precision of 20.  He requested precision out to `decimals` which I clearly demonstrated in my answer.

Comment: what happens when the user enters 20? You cannot tell what the user will enter.

Comment: You're right, which is why I suggested to use the second code snippet in my answer.

Comment: You need to try both using str.format and round, you won't get the required precision using round

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. That does work past the limits.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: You are technically correct, and I agree that formatting possibly fits better than rounding here, but your argument doesn't matter in practice; Any additional digits that your method displays beyond this method are completely meaningless because of the precision of the underlying representation. (You can eg. compare `'{:.{}f}'.format(ratio, 100)` and `'{:.{}f}'.format(ratio + 2e-16, 100)` to see what I mean; the decimals beyond the 16th one are essentially random, so displaying them doesn't make a lot of sense, unless you eg. want fixed-width output or something)